# Convert Column to Row in Excel using macro

Tags: excel, macros

I have a column as below.
A
B
C
D

I need to convert this to as a row mentioned below in a separate sheet in excel file.
A B C D
How can i used macro for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this sub:

```
Sub ColumnToRow()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
      Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).Select
       Selection.Copy
       Sheets("Sheet2").Select
      Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```